# Javascript - remove duplicate entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, duplicates

I am trying to code a workaround for [this bug](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/issues/346) I have with the gem nested_form. No knowledge of ruby/rails is required, it's all gonna be about javascript.

So in a nutshell, when my page reloads, I have some duplicate fields with the same model ID (in the value attribute of hidden inputs).

EDIT : added a non-duplicated input with value 50, that should not be modified

```
<tbody class="echange fields>
   ...
   <input id="etude_echanges_attributes_0_id" type="hidden" name="etude[echanges_attributes][0][id]" value="42">
</tbody>
<tbody class="echange fields>
  ...
  <input id="etude_echanges_attributes_1_id" type="hidden" name="etude[echanges_attributes][1][id]" value="42">
</tbody>
<tbody class="echange fields>
  ...
  <input id="etude_echanges_attributes_2_id" type="hidden" name="etude[echanges_attributes][1][id]" value="50">
</tbody>
```

The 2 first inputs have value 42. Only the last one is the good one, the first one is a duplicate. So basically I would need a code that scans for all `id=".*attributes_x_id"` and their `value`, and only keep the last one.

So in the example I gave above, the javascript should detect that ...

```
<input id="etude_echanges_attributes_0_id" ... value="42">
<input id="etude_echanges_attributes_1_id" ... value="42">
```

...have the same value of `42`, which means they are duplicates

Then it will remove all but the last one. Also the following should not be modified because it's the only one with model ID value 50

```
<input id="etude_echanges_attributes_2_id" ... value="50">
```

EDIT : the parameters that can change are

- The identifier of the model : what is before the `_attributes`
- an HTML id : the xxx in `_attribute_xxx`
- a model ID, which correspond to the value of the `input` : `value="yyy"`

(note 42 and 50 are just examples, the real ones are MongoDB IDs, that look like 5470b5075374611500040000)

**What I want to do :**

1. Find `<input>` that correspond to duplicates of the same instance model (see above)
2. Process all but the last one doing :
3. extract `echanges` from `_echanges_attributes_`
4. singularize it so it becomes `echange`
5. Find the parent by its class "echange fields"
6. Remove this element from the DOM

For now the step that is a problem for me is step n°1. I don't know if it's posible to do it with a simple jquery/css selector ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do this in jQuery:

```
$('input[id^="etude_echanges_attributes"][value="42"]:not(:last)').remove();
```

We match the `id` to ensure we get the right `<input>`s, and not just any `<input>`. Since `id` has a variable value, we cannot use `#`. So instead we use the attribute selector to match the prefixed value. Also threw in `value` in the selector.

Comment: Oh sorry let me give a better example. We need to match duplicates by their value and part of their ID like you did, but not JUST the ID

Comment: @CyrilDD It's just a matter of adding in the match for `value`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know in advance the value is going to be 42.... It could be whatever number. It's the ID of an entry in a database.

Here the variable parameters are :
what is before the `_attribute`, the number after the attribute `_attribute_xxx_`, the value `value="yyy"`

Comment: @CyrilDD the selector is just a string right there. You can chop off 42 and augment a variable.

Comment: The variable in question is a mongoid ID, so a VERY long string with not just numbers (I edited my question)
Maybe I should scan first for all the values, and then do a jquery request like this one for each of them ?